# Cyrillic footnote

Tags: footnotes, cyrillic

I'm trying to make a footnote which contains Cyrillic text, the problem is that LaTeX doesn't make the footnote. The text just appears as normal text in the main document (Though it does show the Cyrillic text).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show a small sample of code that produces the issue?

Comment: \footnote{Добро}

Comment: This doesn't help, sorry. I meant a full (but small) document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: I suppose you load `babel` with  secondary language `russian`, say. Then `\footnote{\selectlanguage{russian}Добро} ` should work, if you use a font which has cyrillic glyphs.

Comment: @Bernard Surely ***not*** `\selectlanguage{russian}`. Maybe you were thinking to `\foreignlanguage{russian}{Добро}`, didn't you?

Comment: No, I used it in preparing the layout of a book by a friend of mine a few months ago, alternating french and russian in the footnote. Of course it would be much simpler to do with `fontspec`. *Added:* I've just taken a look at the documentation, and  I've seen what `\foreignlanguage` does. It would have been better indeed. Actually, I didn't know this command, or had forgotten it, as I very rarely have to switch language in a document.

Answer (score 1):

Without an example it's difficult to say what's going wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

Good\footnote{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Добро} means `good' in English}

\end{document}
```

(For producing the picture, I reduced the text height.)

[image]